# EF 4.2 Code First Query Interception and Navigation Properties

Tags: entity-framework-4

Note: The actual entities in my project are different.  The scenario you are about to read is a simplified example. My actual example affects many more entities than are listed here.

In my project, I have a Member and Group classes as follows:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

My DbContext implementation (ModelBuilder code omitted):

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I have a requirement to enforce the DbContext only return Groups and Members whose Name starts with "X".  I can implement this by changing the Db class as follows:

```
public class Db : DbContext
{
    public IQueryable<Group> Groups
    {
        get
        {
        return from g in ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).CreateQuery<Group>("SELECT VALUE Groups FROM Groups")
                where g.Name.StartsWith("X")
                select g;
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<Member> Members
    {
        get
        {
        return from m in ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).CreateQuery<Member>("SELECT VALUE Members FROM Members")
                where m.Name.StartsWith("X")
                select m;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, queries like the following only return members and groups with names starting with "X":

```
var members = db.Members.ToList();
var groups = db.Groups.ToList();
```

The problem here has to do with INCLUDES...

```
var members = db.Members.Include(m => m.Groups).ToList();
var groups = db.Groups.Include(g => g.Members).ToList();
```

While the "members" list only has "members" whose names start with "X", the Groups property contains Group objects with names that don't comply.  The same pattern applies to the "groups" list, with Member objects that don't comply.

Is there a feature in EF 4.2 that I am missing?

How can I affect queries generated from navigation properties?

Answer (score 1):

Note: I realize this can use some refinement.  It works in my scenario.  Code not guaranteed to compile.

What I ended up building is a way to override the execution of the query and combine the method described at [Tip 37 - How to do a Conditional Include](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx) to populate the DbContext's cache with the desired related objects.

Design goals:

- Provide a way to intercept query execution
- Need to prevent certain "Include" statements from executing while knowing which navigation properties the writer of the query meant to "Include"
- Need to populate the cache and redirect the query to the cache, preventing unnecessary calls to the remote store

To intercept a query:

- Create a `ReLinqContext<T>`
- Set include filtering options (optional)
- Define the intercept function, which accepts an `IQueryable<T>` and returns an `IQueryable<T>` and assign the function to the `ReLinqContext<T>`
- Define a base query, and call the `AsReLinqQuery()` extension method, passing in the `ReLinqContext<T>` from above

With the additional classes below in play, I can change the my DbContext properties as follows:

---

### Example Body of Get for DbContext.Groups property

```
// Enables tracking of ReLinq queries
var ctx = new ReLinqContext<Group>();

// Configures ctx to log, but avoid execution of the Include(string) method
ctx.DisableIncludes();

ctx.Intercept = q =>
{
    // Extract the ObjectQuery<T> out of the DbSet<T>
    // This must be done for q.ChangeSource to work
    var groups = from a in Set<Group>.AsObjectQuery();

    // Rewrite the query to point to a new data source...
    var rewrittenQ = q.ChangeSource(groups);

    // load the results into the context...
    rewrittenQ.Load();

    // Get group ids from the cache
    var groupIds = (from g in Set<Group>().Local
                    select g.Id).ToList();

    // Load respective Member objects into the context...
    if (ctx.IncludePaths.Contains("Members"))
    {
        var members = from m in Set<Member>()
                      from g in m.Groups
                      where groupIds.Contains(g.Id) && m.Name.StartsWith("X")
                      select m;

        members.Load();
    }

    // Add additional if (ctx.IncludePaths.Contains("...")) checks here

    // Return a query that will execute against the DbContext cache
    return q.ChangeSource(Set<Group>().Local.AsQueryable());
};

// The call to ChangeSource during interception
// will allow actual data to be returned.
return new Group[0].AsReLinqQuery(ctx);
```

---

### Additional Code to implement ReLinqQueries

```
public static class ReLinqExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> ChangeSource<T>(this IQueryable<T> oldSource, IQueryable<T> newSource)
    {
        return (IQueryable<T>) QueryableRebinder.Rebind(oldSource, newSource);
    }

    public static IReLinqQuery<T> AsReLinqQuery<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, IReLinqContext<T> context)
    {
        return AsReLinqQuery(enumerable.AsQueryable(), context);
    }

    public static IReLinqQuery<T> AsReLinqQuery<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, IReLinqContext<T> context)
    {
        return new ReLinqQuery<T>(query, (IReLinqContext)context);
    }

    public static IReLinqContext<T> DisableIncludes<T>(this IReLinqContext<T> context)
    {
        context.AllowIncludePath = path => false;
        return context;
    }
}

public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static ObjectQuery<T> AsObjectQuery<T>(this DbSet<T> source) where T : class
    {
        return (ObjectQuery<T>)DbSetUnwrapper.UnWrap(source);
    }
}

public interface IReLinqContext
{
    IList<string> IncludePaths { get; }
    Delegate Intercept { get; }
    Func<string, bool> AllowIncludePath { get; }
}

public interface IReLinqContext<T>
{
    IEnumerable<string> IncludePaths { get; }
    Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> Intercept { get; set; }
    Func<string, bool> AllowIncludePath { get; set; }
}

public class ReLinqContext<T> : IReLinqContext<T>, IReLinqContext
{
    private readonly IList<string> _includePaths; 

    public ReLinqContext()
    {
        _includePaths = new List<string>();
        IncludePaths = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(_includePaths);
        Intercept = q => q;
        AllowIncludePath = path => true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> IncludePaths { get; private set; }
    public Func<IQueryable<T>, IQueryable<T>> Intercept { get; set; }
    public Func<string, bool> AllowIncludePath { get; set; }

    IList<string> IReLinqContext.IncludePaths { get { return _includePaths; }}

    Delegate IReLinqContext.Intercept
    {
        get
        {
            return Intercept;
        }
    }
}

public interface IReLinqQuery<T> : IOrderedQueryable<T>
{
    IReLinqContext<T> Context { get; }
    IReLinqQuery<T> Include(String path);
}

public class ReLinqQuery<T> : IReLinqQuery<T>
{
    public IReLinqContext<T> Context { get; private set; }
    private Expression expression = null;
    private ReLinqQueryProvider provider = null;

    public ReLinqQuery(IQueryable source, IReLinqContext context)
    {
        Context = (IReLinqContext<T>)context;
        expression = Expression.Constant(this);
        provider = new ReLinqQueryProvider(source, context);
    }

    public ReLinqQuery(IQueryable source, IReLinqContext context, Expression e)
    {
        if (e == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("e");
        expression = e;
        provider = new ReLinqQueryProvider(source, context);
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)provider.Execute(expression)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable)provider.Execute(expression)).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public IReLinqQuery<T> Include(String path)
    {
        ((IReLinqContext)Context).IncludePaths.Add(path);

        if (!Context.AllowIncludePath(path))
        {
            return this;
        }

        var possibleObjectQuery = provider.Source as DbQuery<T>;

        if (possibleObjectQuery != null)
        {
            return new ReLinqQuery<T>(possibleObjectQuery.Include(path), (IReLinqContext)Context);
        }

        return this;
    }

    public Type ElementType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }

    public Expression Expression
    {
        get { return expression; }
    }

    public IQueryProvider Provider
    {
        get { return provider; }
    }
}

public class ReLinqQueryProvider : IQueryProvider
{
    internal IQueryable Source { get; private set; }
    internal IReLinqContext Context { get; private set; }

    public ReLinqQueryProvider(IQueryable source, IReLinqContext context)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        Source = source;
        Context = context;
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        return new ReLinqQuery<TElement>(Source, Context, expression);
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        Type elementType = expression.Type.GetGenericArguments().Single();
        IQueryable result = (IQueryable)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(ReLinqQuery<>).MakeGenericType(elementType),
                new object[] { Source, Context, expression });
        return result;
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");
        object result = (this as IQueryProvider).Execute(expression);
        return (TResult)result;
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        if (expression == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("expression");

        var translated = ReLinqQueryUnwrapper.UnWrap(expression, Source);
        var translatedQuery = Source.Provider.CreateQuery(translated);
        //var query = CreateQuery(expression);

        var interceptedQuery = Context.Intercept.DynamicInvoke(translatedQuery);

        return interceptedQuery;
    }
} 

public class ReLinqQueryUnwrapper : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly IQueryable _source;

    public static Expression UnWrap(Expression expression, IQueryable source)
    {
        var queryTranslator = new ReLinqQueryUnwrapper(source);

        return queryTranslator.Visit(expression);
    }

    public ReLinqQueryUnwrapper(IQueryable source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    #region Visitors
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        if (c.Type == typeof(ReLinqQuery<>).MakeGenericType(_source.ElementType))
        {
            return _source.Expression;
        }

        return base.VisitConstant(c);
    }
    #endregion
}

public class DbSetUnwrapper : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public static IQueryable UnWrap(IQueryable source)
    {
        var dbSetUnwrapper = new DbSetUnwrapper(source);
        dbSetUnwrapper.Visit(source.Expression);
        return dbSetUnwrapper._target;
    }

    private readonly IQueryable _source;
    private IQueryable _target;

    public DbSetUnwrapper(IQueryable source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if(node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            var c = (ConstantExpression) node;

            if (c.Type == typeof(ObjectQuery<>).MakeGenericType(_source.ElementType))
            {
                _target = (IQueryable)c.Value;
            }
        }

        return base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public class QueryableRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private IQueryable _oldSource;
    private IQueryable _newSource;

    public static IQueryable Rebind(IQueryable oldSource, IQueryable newSource)
    {
        var queryTranslator = new QueryableRebinder(oldSource, newSource);

        return newSource.Provider.CreateQuery(queryTranslator.Visit(oldSource.Expression));
    }

    public QueryableRebinder(IQueryable oldSource, IQueryable newSource)
    {
        _oldSource = oldSource;
        _newSource = newSource;
    }

    #region Visitors
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
    {
        if (typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(_oldSource.ElementType).IsAssignableFrom(c.Type))
        {
            return Expression.Constant(_newSource);
        }

        return base.VisitConstant(c);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through [Tip 37 – How to do a Conditional Include](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/10/13/tip-37-how-to-do-a-conditional-include.aspx).

Comment: Upvoting because your answer ultimately led me to the solution, although it did take some work :-).

Comment: Well, since I am new, I didn't know upvotes required 15 rep points....so I would have!

Comment: More detail in the answer I posted below.  I didn't mark this as the accepted answer because the actual answer took a lot of work beyond your suggestion.  Thanks though for the pointer.